# Why does deadlock occur on calling Semaphore.WaitOne?

Tags: c#, deadlock, semaphore

The `run()` function in the following code is called from other threads simultaneously. At anytime, on any line, a ThreadAbortException might occur according to the general design of the application, which I cannot change.

I sometimes get `SemaphoreFullException` while calling `pool.Release()`. I think this occurs if a thread abort exception occurs while calling "pool.WaitOne()". During my debug tries, after SemaphoreFullException has occurred, there is no problem in running the code. After that exception, `pool.WaitOne()` calls and other things work just as expected.

I haven't been able to get a deadlock situation during my local debug sessions. However, in a remote computer, I have a deadlock with this code. I attach that process using remote debugger and see that the execution is locked on the line `pool.WaitOne();`.

I can't figure out how this would happen, and what I'm doing wrong. Any help is very appreciated.

```
private static object poolLocker = new object();
private static Semaphore _pool;
private static Semaphore pool
{
    get
    {
       if (_pool == null)
           lock (poolLocker)
       if (_pool == null)
       {
           int count = myMaximumThreadCount;
           _pool = new Semaphore(count, count);
       }
       return _pool;
    }
}

private void run()
{
    try
    {
        pool.WaitOne();

        do_something_that_may_throw_exception();
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            pool.Release();
        }
        catch (SemaphoreFullException) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your investigation won't be helped by code that silently hides exceptions (the empty `catch` block)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thank you for your suggestion. I've changed that part only to catch SemaphoreFullException, and the same deadlock occurred on the remote computer. All the unhandled exceptions are reported; no exception was reported.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the initialization of the semaphore object in `pool` property to:

```
private static Semaphore pool
{
    get
    {
       if (_pool == null)
           lock (poolLocker)
       if (_pool == null)
       {
           int count = myMaximumThreadCount;
           _pool = new Semaphore(0, count);
       }
       return _pool;
    }
}
```

An initial count for this semaphore should be set to zero.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the cause of the deadlock; and it has nothing to do with the question I've asked, so this is a bad question, sorry for that. There seems to be no problem in the code in the question.

The cause: In the do_something_that_may_throw_exception() function, an extern function of a C++ library is being called. When an error occurs in the C++ function, a SEHException is thrown. However, in my tries this exception can only be caught in a function that has HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions and SecurityCritical attributes. And that function happens to call the run() function of the question. However, the **finally part of the run() function is newer executed!** Also, if you have a using(IDisposable object){ ... }  and the SEHException occurs inside it; object's Dispose() function won't be called.

I've used the following function for calling the C++ function; and everything worked fine:

```
SafeCall(()=> call_external_cpp_function());

[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
[SecurityCritical]
internal static void SafeCall(Action action)
{
    try
    {
        action();
    }
    catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException) { throw; }
    catch (System.Threading.ThreadInterruptedException) { throw; }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```